# Write recursive function that acts like sys.getrecursionlimit

Tags: python, recursion

How to write a recursive function that acts like sys.getrecursionlimit, thus getting the recursion limit without importing any libraries?

```
def recurse(n):
m = 0
def recurse2(n):
    nonlocal m 
    m = m+1
    n-recurse2(n-1)
try: 
    recurse2(n)
except RecursionError:
    print(m)
```

This is what I've attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easiest to pass a counter down to each function rather than try to access variables out of the function scope:

```
def get_limit():
    try:
        return 1 + get_limit()
    except RecursionError:
        return 2
```

which gives `1000` for me - just like `sys.getrecursionlimit()`.

---

**why?**

So on every call of the function, the function adds one to the result of how many more recursive calls can be made. The answer to this question "how many [more] recursive calls can be made?" is simply answered by the function itself, so we return `1` + `get_limit()` since we were called so we must return one more.

Finally, we must define a base case which will lie at the bottom of the tree and handle when the answer to "how many [more] recursive calls can be made?" is `RecursionError`, i.e. "no more". In this case, the true answer is `1`, but since the actual function will be called once, we should return `2` to account for the call at the top of the tree/stack so that our result is, in my case, `1000` rather than the `999` that it would be if we returned `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try/except` inside the recursive function to be able to return the depth counter:

```
def _get_recursion_limit(n = 1):
  try:
     return _get_recursion_limit(n+1)
  except RecursionError:
     return n+1 #account for last attempt with increment

import sys
print(_get_recursion_limit())
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

Output:

```
1000
1000
```

On my machine, both results are `1000`.